# What is the PMF of the Zero-Truncated Skellam distribution?

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, truncated-distributions, skellam-distribution

Vaguely related to the notion of a [Lindley equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindley_equation),

I am considering a recurrence

$$L_{t+1} := L_t +  \max \left( 0, A_t - S_t \right)$$

where

$$L_t$$

is the number of customers in a queue system at time $t$ and

$$A_t \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_t)$$

is the number of arrivals at time $t$ and

$$S_t \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu_t)$$

is the number of served customers at time $t$. The initial number of customers in the system, $L_0$, is a given non-negative integer.

Assuming that $A_t$ and $S_t$ are independent for all $t$, I expect that their difference follows a [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution):

$$A_t - S_t \sim \text{Skellam}(\lambda_t, \mu_t).$$

One can further consider $U_t := \max \left( 0, A_t - S_t \right)$ to follow a zero-truncated (from below) Skellam distribution. I would expect the [truncated distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) PMF to resemble:

$$G_{U_t}(u_t; \lambda_t, \mu_t) = \frac{\exp \left(- (\lambda_t + \mu_t) \right) \left( \frac{\lambda_t}{\mu_t} \right)^{\frac{k}{2}} I_k (2 \sqrt{\lambda_t \mu_t})}{1 - F_{A_t - S_t}(0)}.$$

Only trouble is that I cannot seem to find a closed form for evaluating $F_{A_t - S_t}(0)$.

---

Either a closed form or an approximation with known error bounds would be acceptable for an answer.

Comment: If $\mu_t$ isn't large, you could just sum the Skellam dist'n from $0$ to $-k$, where $k$ is large enough so that the probability is tiny; that should be pretty fast.